# Access violation when thread calls callback, modifying a QObject

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, boost

**My solution is in the second update**

I've written a class that has what's essentially an endless loop in which it reacts to network events. This runs fine in a console application.
I have now attempted to use said class in a Qt GUI application. The window only contains a QPlainTextEdit (and an as of yet unused QLineEdit) in which I want my class to write what it would usually output on the console.
For this, I have created a callback function (called `outputLine` in the bot class) which calls `plainTextEdit.appendPlainText` and gave it to my class for it to use, using `boost::function` and `boost::bind` to make it work.

An access violation happens, when the callback function is called here (the bot class source file):

```cpp
char outputData[MAXDATASIZE];
iResult = recv(s, receive_buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0);
if (iResult > 0){
   numbytes = iResult;
   receive_buf[numbytes]='\0';
   sprintf(outputData, "%s: <<< %s", time_now(), receive_buf); 
   outputLine(std::string(outputData));
```

Interestingly though, no access violation is caused by this:

```cpp
char temp[100];
sprintf(temp, "test %i", someInteger);
outputLine(temp);
```

The access violation can be prevented, if I comment out the `appendPlainText(t)` line (see next code block), if I do so, everything works fine (I confirmed this by checking the IRC server the bot is connecting to: it joins the channel and answers my commands).

Here's the relevant code in the Qt source files:

```cpp
void QtTigerAutomaton::outputLine(std::string t){
    ui.plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(t.c_str());
}

QtTigerAutomaton::QtTigerAutomaton(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    bot.setupBot("NICK somenick\r\n", "USER guest host server :some name\r\n", 
                 boost::bind(&QtTigerAutomaton::outputLine, this, _1));
}
void QtTigerAutomaton::onConnectClick(){
    botThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&IrcBot::start, &bot));
}
```

Here's the (hopefully) relevant code from the bot class:
header file:

```cpp
typedef boost::function<void (std::string)> callbacktype;
/* ... */
callbacktype outputLine; //outputLine is assigned in setupBot
```

What causes this access violation and how can I prevent it?

PS: Better solutions as to how to display the bot class's output in Qt are of course greatly appreciated, too. My goal is to be able to send my bot commands using its GUI which is impossible using the console application format I was using before.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to an answer, I believe now that the problem is that QWidgets etc. are not thread safe, therefore I converted my bot to a QObject and am now attempting to use the signal/slot mechanism as follows:

In QtTigerAutomaton's constructor, I added

```
connect(&bot, SIGNAL(bot.outputSignal(const QString)), this, 
        SLOT(onOutputNeeded(const QString)));`
```

I realize I could've used `ui.plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(const QString)` directly but I wanted to have more control over what's happening for debug purposes.

more relevant code:

```
/* IrcBot.h */
public:
void testLine(){
    emit outputSignal("testing");
};
signals:
    void outputSignal(const QString);
```

however, calling `bot.testLine()` does nothing. Am I using the connect function wrongly, or what is my mistake?

**UPDATE**

The correct syntax for the connect statement is
`connect(&bot, SIGNAL(outputSignal(const QString)), this, SLOT(onOutputNeeded(const QString)));`
and it does seem to work now.

The solution to the problem was, indeed, to use the signal/slot mechanism, which is clearly a lot more elegant than the callback function and it actually works. Thanks for everyone's help!

Here's a step by step:

Converted my IrcBot class to a QObject class and added a signal to be emitted:

```
#include <qobject.h>

class IrcBot : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

/* ... */

signals:
    void outputSignal(const QString);
```

connected the signal like this:

```
connect(&bot, SIGNAL(outputSignal(const QString)), ui.plainTextEdit, 
        SLOT(appendPlainText(const QString)));
```

emitted the signal whenever some output was generated as follows:

```
emit outputSignal("some text"); //or various ways to generate output QStrings
```

Now, no Access Violations happen and the text is displayed in the plainTextEdit as I wanted it.

PS: is there a way to mark my question as answered now? Since I can't answer to my own question I don't know how :x I'm new here.

Comment: What does `appendPlainText` do? It sounds like there are some special requirements for the conditions under which this function can be called that your code doesn't comply with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! According to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qplaintextedit.html#appendPlainText), the function has no specific requirements... But I just realized it's a slot, so maybe I can turn my bot into a QObject and have it emit a signal, then connect the two, instead of using a callback...

Comment: QWidgets/QObjects aren't threadsafe, so you cannot call their methods directly from another thread. As you already did, signal/slots is the best solution here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I expected it to be a thread safety problem... I have no attempted to do the signal/slot thing, but it seems the slot function is not called when the signal is emitted - I will update my initial post with some more code to show what I did. I'm sure it's just some simple error...

Comment: @JayEff Doesn't it have the general requirement that no thread may access an object while another thread is, or might be, modifying it? And, if so, if you're going to call a modification function, which `appendPlainText` is, the special requirement for the condition under which the function can be called is that no other thread can be accessing the object you are modifying.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, that would make sense, and that would explain why it worked sometimes, and sometimes it didn't. I've had this idea, too, but couldn't find a solution for it. Do you think using the signal/slot mechanism as I am attempting now could solve this problem? Or do you have another idea as to how I could get around this?

Comment: I seem to have solved the problem thanks to you guys, now to mark this as solved ...